# Jenkins deploy on tomcat remove manager and users

Tags: tomcat

I have remove tomcat manager and all user on my production. So how i can deploy my build war file on tomcat using jenking.I want deploy without any tomcat manager.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy your `myApp.war` file to `apacht-tomcat/webapps` folder. This would deploy it on context path `/myApp` making it accessible via `http://localhost:8080/myApp`.

Alternatively you can place a context XML descriptor in

`apache-tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/myOtherWebApp.xml` with the content:

```
<Context docBase="/path/to/myApp.war" path="/myOtherWebApp"/>
```

This would deploy it on context path `/myOtherWebApp` making it accessible via `http://localhost:8080/myOtherWebApp`.